# Spectrum of an operator vs spectrum of a matrix

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

The spectrum of a bounded operator is a generalisation of the set of eigenvalues of a matrix. If $T$ is a bounded operator and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda$ is an element of the spectrum of $T$.

The spectrum of a matrix is the set of its eigenvalues. If $T$ is a bounded linear operator over a finite-dimensional vector space, then its spectrum equals the set of its eigenvalues. This does not always hold in the case of infinite-dimensional spaces, consider for example the shift operator on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

I was wondering, what can we say about the relation between the set of eigenvalues of a bounded operator $T$ and its spectrum, when the bounded operator $T$ is a matrix? Do we have to make a distinction between finite-dimensional matrices and infinite-dimensional matrices?

In other words: are the definitions "spectrum of a bounded operator" and "spectrum of a matrix" compatible?

Comment: My take on the question: when you choose a basis of your Hilbert space the bounded operators have matrices in that basis, so there's no distinction between the spectrum of a matrix and the spectrum of an operator. This is exactly the same as the finite dimensional situation, when all linear transformations are bounded. There too you make no distinction between the spectrum of a matrix and the spectrum of a transformation. I've posted this as a comment rather than an answer because it's a long time since I did any analysis and there may be some subtlety I'm missing.

Comment: There is no difference. Bounded operator spectral theory, in finite dimension, amounts exactly to the usual spectral theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however a bounded operator can be defined on a vector space which is not necessarily a Hilbert space...

Comment: Eigenvalues are always going to be part of the spectrum. Now, in the infinite dimensional case, the spectrum can have many other points and it is possible for none of them to be eigenvalues. the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)) has all the basic explanation already, so there is no point in re-writing it here.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of eigenvalue is about operators. We use it on matrices because we can see them as operators. I say this because the definition of eigenvalue survives similarity, which means it is independent of basis, and thus it is independent of the form of the operator as a matrix.

Namely, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then for any invertible $S$ we have $(SAS^{-1})Sx=\lambda Sx$. So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, it is also an eigenvalue of $SAS^{-1}$, so it is still an eigenvalue of $A$ in any basis.

In infinite dimension things change, first as you mention because the useful notion of spectrum goes beyond that of eigenvalue. Second, because there is no immediate way to define the notion of eigenvalue of an infinite matrix other than as an operator (i.e., $Ax=\lambda x$). There is no general infinite-dimensional analog of $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$.